# Rate limiting in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rate-limiting

I have to design a system where there are two types of rate limiter on the downstream application :

1. Requests per second
2. Requests per minute

```
For eg : I can make 300 requests per hour to the downstream application and 10 requests per second. So I can make 200 API calls in first 20 seconds and remaining 100 API calls after 25 minutes. OR any combination possible.
```

I am developing project in springboot. Is there any library which can help in implementing both type of rate limits for downstream application?

Comment: Are you using Azure or AWS? I would use API management for this job

Comment: As @VovaBilyachat already asked. Where will you run the app?

Comment: we are using spring cloud gateway with redis rate limiter. you can check this out

Comment: I am using AWS for running the app.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html